# How to obtain "\ " instead " " after a sed substitution?

Tags: sed, escape-characters

I use a string that contains `\` in a `sed` expression and I want to keep it in the output of `sed`

```
$ A=w
$ B="\ "
$ echo word | sed "s/$A/$B/"
   ord
```

I want to obtain `\ ord` instead of `ord`.

What is the most elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape both the shell, and `sed`:

```
$ A=w
$ B="\\\ "
$ echo word | sed "s/$A/$B/"
\ ord
```